# Oracle: Viewing settings for DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN ACL?

Tags: oracle, acl

How do I view the contents of a network ACL? For example, if I create this ACL, how can I view what settings have been applied to it?

```
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(
     acl => 'www.xml',
     description => 'WWW ACL',
     principal => 'SCOTT',
     is_grant => true,
     privilege => 'connect'
  );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to see also implicit privileges you can use this query:

```
SELECT PRINCIPAL, HOST, lower_port, upper_port, acl, 'connect' AS PRIVILEGE, 
    DECODE(DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE_ACLID(aclid, PRINCIPAL, 'connect'), 1,'GRANTED', 0,'DENIED', NULL) PRIVILEGE_STATUS
FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
    JOIN DBA_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES USING (ACL, ACLID)  
UNION ALL
SELECT PRINCIPAL, HOST, NULL lower_port, NULL upper_port, acl, 'resolve' AS PRIVILEGE, 
    DECODE(DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE_ACLID(aclid, PRINCIPAL, 'resolve'), 1,'GRANTED', 0,'DENIED', NULL) PRIVILEGE_STATUS
FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
    JOIN DBA_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES USING (ACL, ACLID);
```

Answer (score 3):

Two views:

[DBA_NETWORK_ACLS](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-8B562C24-D87B-4A39-BAE7-F268EA05E12C.htm#REFRN23711)

[DBA_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-DE415659-8519-456A-BEF0-A5A42B6D6A0C.htm#REFRN23712)